# Can't save extended User properties in .NET 8 Identity UI (Blazor Server)

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side

I want to extend the Identity User with custom properties, and use the Identity UI to update them. But I can't get data to be saved.

Steps to reproduce the issue, using Visual Studio 17.9.0 Community edition, with .NET SDK v8.0.201:

1. Create a new Blazor Wep App with .NET 8, Individual Accounts, Interactive render mode: Server, Interactivity location: Global.
2. Modify the connection string in /appsettings.json if needed. Mine looks like this:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=ExtendedUserPropertiesDemo2; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
```

3. Using the Package Management Console (PMC), apply the templated initial migration and create the database by running

> update-database

4. Open up /Data/ApplicationUser.cs and add new properties:

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

5. In the PMC, create a new migration by running:

> add-migration ApplicationUser_AddNameProps

6. Update the database again:

> update-database

7. Open up the user management page (/Components/Account/Pages/Manage/Index.razor)
8. In the `InputModel`, at the bottom of the file, add the same properties we added in the `ApplicationUser` model, so it looks like this:

```
    private sealed class InputModel
    {
        [Phone]
        [Display(Name = "Phone number")]
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

9. Update the form to include form fields for the new properties:

```
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="..." />
        <label for="first-name" class="form-label">First Name</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.FirstName" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText @bind-Value="Input.LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="..." />
        <label for="last-name" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.LastName" class="text-danger" />
    </div>
```

10. In `OnInitializedAsync()`, add:

```
    Input.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    Input.LastName = user.LastName;
```

`OnInitializedAsync()` now looks like this:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    user = await UserAccessor.GetRequiredUserAsync(HttpContext);
    username = await UserManager.GetUserNameAsync(user);
    phoneNumber = await UserManager.GetPhoneNumberAsync(user);

    Input.PhoneNumber ??= phoneNumber;
    Input.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    Input.LastName = user.LastName;
}
```

11. In `OnValidSubmitAsync()`, add:

```
    user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
    user.LastName = Input.LastName;
    await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

`OnValidSubmitAsync()` now looks like this:

```
private async Task OnValidSubmitAsync()
{
    if (Input.PhoneNumber != phoneNumber)
    {
        var setPhoneResult = await UserManager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, Input.PhoneNumber);
        if (!setPhoneResult.Succeeded)
        {
            RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Error: Failed to set phone number.", HttpContext);
        }
    }

    user.FirstName = Input.FirstName;
    user.LastName = Input.LastName;
    await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    await SignInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);
    RedirectManager.RedirectToCurrentPageWithStatus("Your profile has been updated", HttpContext);
}
```

12. Run the application.
13. Register a user and confirm the account.
14. Log in and access the user management page (/Account/Manage) by clicking on your registered e-mail address in the menu.
15. Enter data in the `FirstName`, `LastName` and `PhoneNumber` form fields. Click "Save".
16. Observe that the phone number is persisted, but the names are not.

Did I miss a step? How is this supposed to be done?